# What would be the regex to find an annotation without any parameters

Tags: regex, replace

```
@ManyToOne
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
```

I would like to query for all lines which end with @ManyToOne without any parameters. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
@ManyToOne$
```

E.g. in C#:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("@ManyToOne$");

Console.WriteLine("Matches: " + rgx.IsMatch("@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)")); //Matches: false
Console.WriteLine("Matches: " + rgx.IsMatch("@ManyToOne")); //Matches: true
```